# Connecting Lines in a Single Elimination UI with an Odd Number of Players - react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I'm building a `Single Elimination UI` using `React` and `CSS`, and I've got an issue when trying to connect lines between players.

I tried this way. drawn a line over it. but structure got failed. Here's the code i tried  https://codesandbox.io/s/single-elimination-torunament-forked-qqlxm4?file=/src/SingleElimination.jsx
But it failed due to improper structure of boxes. and lines are not drawing if it not comes under viewport

[image]

required structure was

[image]

please suggest me with some solutions.

Comment: I wish people could show demos like this on every other question on SO. Simple way to understand ;)

Comment: maybe you can use canvas or svg, it's possible apply css in svg subtags

Comment: @BrumazziDB, ya. I used svgs for drawing lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, i'd prefer to use another HTML for the connecting lines, but I don't want to change your code so much just for that, so in this solution, i'm sticking to use SVG for drawing the lines.

First thing is that, to make a structure similar to the second picture, you'd need to add the "ghost" box, so I added this:

```
const players15 = {
    round1: [
      [], // need to add this
      [8, 9],
...
```

And then I made the CSS so that the box are vertically centered (many CSS codes tweaked, can't really show which ones because there are too many).

After the CSS is fixed, I realized that you connected some boxes to wrong boxes:

```
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match2", ".round2match1", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match2", ".round2match2", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match3", ".round2match1", newLines);
```

I'd assume that you don't want to connect `round1match2` with `round2match1`, while also connecting `round1match2` with `round2match2` (like why would one box be connected to two boxes on the next round?), so I fixed them according to the second picture also:

```
      // round 1 to 2
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match2", ".round2match1", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match3", ".round2match2", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match4", ".round2match2", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match5", ".round2match3", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match6", ".round2match3", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match7", ".round2match4", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round1match8", ".round2match4", newLines);

      // round 2 to 3
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round2match1", ".round3match1", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round2match2", ".round3match1", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round2match3", ".round3match2", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round2match4", ".round3match2", newLines);

      // round 3 to 4
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round3match1", ".round4match1", newLines);
      drawConnectorsBetweenMatches(".round3match2", ".round4match1", newLines);
```

After that, I realized that the lines are still not rendered correctly, so I had to tweak the lines placements. Basically I changed your code to this:

```
    let midPointX =
      (match1Rect.right + match2Rect.left) / 2 + scrollLeft - playoffTableLeft;

    newLines.push({
      x1: midPointX,
      y1: match1Rect.top + match1Rect.height / 2 + window.scrollY - offsetTop,
      x2: midPointX,
      y2: match2Rect.top + match2Rect.height / 2 + window.scrollY - offsetTop
    });
    newLines.push({
      x1: match1Rect.right + scrollLeft - 20 - playoffTableLeft,
      y1: match1Rect.top + match1Rect.height / 2 + window.scrollY - offsetTop,
      x2: midPointX,
      y2: match1Rect.top + match1Rect.height / 2 + window.scrollY - offsetTop
    });
    newLines.push({
      x1: match2Rect.left + scrollLeft + 20 - playoffTableLeft,
      y1: match2Rect.top + match2Rect.height / 2 + window.scrollY - offsetTop,
      x2: midPointX,
      y2: match2Rect.top + match2Rect.height / 2 + window.scrollY - offsetTop
    });
```

Basically, I added them so that the calculations will reflect to viewport changes.

Then I also removed this line because i'm not sure if it's still necessary:

```
    playoffTable.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
```

This is how it looks like now:
[image]

Here is the forked sandbox:

[image: Edit single-elimination-torunament-forked-zxp277]

### EDIT:

Since OP said that they can't manually add the empty boxes, I offer solution where the empty boxes are added automatically, this solution even connects the lines automatically.

So since it's essentially a binary tree data structure, we could just iterate from the root (the last round) and see if there are any value which aren't "tbd", and if it's not "tbd", we can add empty boxes on the previous round so that the CSS will hold out, this is the function:

```
  function populateTree(obj) {
    const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    const round = Math.max(
      ...Object.keys(newObj).map((key) =>
        parseInt(key.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, ""))
      )
    );

    let pointer = round;

    while (pointer !== 1) {
      const currRound = newObj[`round${pointer}`].flat(Infinity);

      for (let i = 0; i < currRound.length; i++) {
        if (currRound[i] !== "tbd") {
          newObj[`round${pointer - 1}`].splice(i, 0, [null, null]);
        }
      }
      pointer--;
    }

    return newObj;
  }
```

This could now handle cases where there are winners already:

[image]

This is the new forked codesandbox:

[image: Edit single-elimination-torunament-forked-jj5xty]

Comment: Thanks. But I cant add empty boxes in array. They come from the backend. Like for 5 players, it will be like this  const players5 = { round1: [[4, 5]], round2: [ ["1", "tbd"], [2, 3] ], round3: [["tbd", "tbd"]] };so I dont know where to add empty boxes. They wont sent bye matches.

Comment: @smackcherry ok, wouldn't that just mean we can add empty box to the one that is NOT tbd on the next column?

Comment: yes. I think it will work out...

Comment: @smackcherry please check my updated answer

Comment: Is it possible to decrease the empty space. pic link:  https://postimg.cc/tY6Z57Vk

Comment: @smackcherry i don't know, can you imagine how it looks like without the empty space? It will look terrible I imagine, also I think you start to ask more than what you state in the question

Comment: ok.. Thanks a lot for helping me.......

Comment: @smackcherry you can make a new question to solve that part (reducing the empty space), I (or someone else) might help

Comment: okay.... sure.....